# Short captions for LaTeX tables with stargazer

Tags: r, latex, knitr, sweave, stargazer

In LaTeX, a short captions (that will appear in the List of Figures) can be made with the following code:

```
  \caption[Short caption.]{Long caption.}
```

With `stargazer` in R I tried this:

```
stargazer(mtcars, summary = FALSE, title="[Short caption]Long caption")
```

Which produces this output for the captions:

```
  \caption{[Short caption]Long caption}
```

How can I make a short caption with `stargazer`?

Comment: There's no update to this? I tried to file an issue to the package's author, but the package doesn't seem to be on github...

Comment: @Heisenberg see here for workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31087731/capture-r-output-and-replace-with-latex-code

Answer (score 0):

Using stargazer you can to disable it's float option. Nesting the stargazer chunk in a manually provided table environment then lets you customize any captions or labels manually, i.e.

```
\begin{table}
\caption[Short caption]{The main caption of the table.}
\label{tab:mtcars}
\centering

<<results="asis",echo=F>>=
stargazer(mtcars[1:5, 1:3], summary = FALSE,float=F)
@

\end{table}
```