# Capture R output and replace with LaTeX code

Tags: r, string, stargazer

I'm trying to capture the output from some R code and replace it with latex code.

If you run this code:

```
library(stargazer)
x <- capture.output(stargazer(mtcars[1:5, 1:3], summary = FALSE, title="The main caption of the table."))

x
```

This is the output:

```
 [1] ""                                                                                                         
 [2] "% Table created by stargazer v.5.1 by Marek Hlavac, Harvard University. E-mail: hlavac at fas.harvard.edu"
 [3] "% Date and time: Sat, Jun 27, 2015 - 11:36:07"                                                            
 [4] "\\begin{table}[!htbp] \\centering "                                                                       
 [5] "  \\caption{The main caption of the table.} "                                                             
 [6] "  \\label{} "                                                                                             
 [7] "\\begin{tabular}{@{\\extracolsep{5pt}} cccc} "                                                            
 [8] "\\\\[-1.8ex]\\hline "                                                                                     
 [9] "\\hline \\\\[-1.8ex] "                                                                                    
[10] " & mpg & cyl & disp \\\\ "                                                                                
[11] "\\hline \\\\[-1.8ex] "                                                                                    
[12] "Mazda RX4 & $21$ & $6$ & $160$ \\\\ "                                                                     
[13] "Mazda RX4 Wag & $21$ & $6$ & $160$ \\\\ "                                                                 
[14] "Datsun 710 & $22.800$ & $4$ & $108$ \\\\ "                                                                
[15] "Hornet 4 Drive & $21.400$ & $6$ & $258$ \\\\ "                                                            
[16] "Hornet Sportabout & $18.700$ & $8$ & $360$ \\\\ "                                                         
[17] "\\hline \\\\[-1.8ex] "                                                                                    
[18] "\\end{tabular} "                                                                                          
[19] "\\end{table} "
```

I need to replace line 5 with this:

```
"  \\caption[short caption]{The main caption of the table.} "
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `x <- sub("\\caption{The main caption of the table.}", "\\caption[short caption]{The main caption of the table.}", fixed = TRUE, x)` ?

Comment: @StevenBeaupré want to add that as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
x <- sub("\\caption{The main caption of the table.}", 
         "\\caption[short caption]{The main caption of the table.}", fixed = TRUE, x)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little different than what you had in mind, but perhaps you could just use `xtable` which has a `caption.width` argument, e.g.:

```
print.xtable(xtable(mtcars[1:5, 1:3],
                    caption="The main caption of the table"),
             caption.width="10cm",
             caption.placement="top")
```

The output will not port *exactly* to what you're going for, but maybe you could bend this to your purposes if you prefer the more concise code; from `?print.xtable`:

> The caption will be placed in a "parbox" of the specified width if caption.width is not NULL and type="latex". Default value is NULL.

Here's the output:

```
% latex table generated in R 3.1.3 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Tue Jun 30 14:52:06 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\parbox{5cm}{\caption{The main caption of the table}} 
\begin{tabular}{rrrr}
  \hline
 & mpg & cyl & disp \\ 
  \hline
Mazda RX4 & 21.00 & 6.00 & 160.00 \\ 
  Mazda RX4 Wag & 21.00 & 6.00 & 160.00 \\ 
  Datsun 710 & 22.80 & 4.00 & 108.00 \\ 
  Hornet 4 Drive & 21.40 & 6.00 & 258.00 \\ 
  Hornet Sportabout & 18.70 & 8.00 & 360.00 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

You'll also have to mess around with the other options (e.g., `digits`) to get the exact formatting of the rest of the table to match that from `stargazer`, depending on what exactly the formatting is that you had in mind.